# Постоянная обработка исключений

Tags: python, python-3.x

Есть 2 файла: *main.py* и *defs.py*.

**defs.py**

```
class Sad:
    def __init__(self,mas):
        self.mas = mas
    def mal(self):
        print(self.mas)
    pass
```

**main.py**

```
 from defs import *

 while True:
    si a= Sad('12324')
     sia.mal()
     print('34334')
```

Нужно сделать так, чтобы `Keyboardinterrupt` убивал программу в любое время, даже когда выполняются методы. Как это будет логичней сделать:
так:

```
while True:
    try:
        sia = Sad('12324')
        sia.mal()
        print('34334')
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        pass
```

или вот так:

```
class Sad:
    def __init__(self,mas):
        try:
            self.mas = mas
        except KeyboardInterrupt:
            pass

    def mal(self):
        try:
            print(self.mas)
        except KeyboardInterrupt:
            pass
    pass
```

PS Зачем мне делать `except`: нужно отключить `webdriver` и потом сделать `exit`.

Comment: `KeyboardInterrupt` и так всегда "убивает" программу. Чего именно Вы хотите добиться? Обработка этого исключения используется как раз для того, чтобы оно НЕ "убивало" программу.

Comment: В показанных вами примерах нет абсолютно ничего про webdriver, из-за чего суть вопроса продолжает оставаться непонятной

Comment: ладно допустим не веб драйвер, допустим перед exit'ом мне надо сделать какой нибудь код

Comment: В main просто цикл оберните в try-except, все подряд оборачивать не нужно.

Comment: А вообще если у вас подключение идёт через конструкцию with, то закрытие подключения произойдёт при выходе из блока With в любом случае, в том числе и при KeyboardInterrupt.

Comment: @SandStadham https://docs.python.org/3/library/atexit.html

Comment: Не по вопросу: избегайте звездочек в импорте (см. руководстве по стилю pep8, раздел Import https://pep8.org/#imports: `Wildcard imports (from <module> import *) should be avoided`). На русском это же руководство: https://pythonworld.ru/osnovy/pep-8-rukovodstvo-po-napisaniyu-koda-na-python.html#id8